# Error with array_unique

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

What am I doing wrong with this?  If I just run this:

```
$region = EM_Locations::get(array('orderby'=>'region_name'));
```

all is good. However when I add in the array_unique:

```
$region = EM_Locations::get(array('orderby'=>'region_name'));
$reg = array_unique($region)
```

It breaks and get "EM_Location could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> array_unique() sorts the values treated as string, two elements are
>   considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2.

You can add [__toString()](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) method for the `EM_Location` class.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

> array_unique() sorts the values treated as string at first, then will
>   keep the first key encountered for every value, and ignore all
>   following keys.

This means that the values must be converted to a string for comparison, but your values appear to be of type `EM_Location`, which PHP can't figure out how to convert to a string.